# DataTable.Select() - Comparing GUIDs

Tags: c#, datatable

I've a datatable with a column containing GUIDs. I want to select a row matching a specific GUID. I wrote the following code,

```
DataRow[] dRows = dtListSettings.Select("ListGUID = " + Convert.ToString(ViewState["GUID"]));
```

The GUID i'm comparing is 500c2b6a-a3a7-457f-90ed-c96768d91520. But i'm getting the error - **Syntax error: Missing operand after 'c2b6a' operator.**

Any ideas?

Thank you
NLV

Comment: Yah, what @ozczecho said. Without the quotes, you're creating a select statement that is attempting a math operation (-).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Need a single quote:

Something like:

```
string.Format("ListGUID = '{0}'", Convert.ToString(ViewState["GUID"]));
```

Comment: You can actually skip the Convert.ToString since String.Format takes Object.

Answer (score 2):

Try surrounding your select statement parameter in single quotes, like this:

```
DataRow[] dRows = dtListSettings.Select("ListGUID = '" + Convert.ToString(ViewState["GUID"]) + "'");
```

Comment: Worked perfect. Thank you.
NLV

Answer (score 2):

This does not work for IN. E.g.

```
DataRow[] dRows = dtListSettings.Select("ListGUID IN ('" + Convert.ToString(ViewState["GUID"]) + "')");
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolve this with two bellow methods:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable(); // your datatable with data
Guid gid = Guid.NewGuid(); // searching guid
DataRow[] dra = dt.Select("GuidColumn = '" + gid.ToString() + "'")
// OR
DataRow[] dra = dt.Select("GuidColumn = Convert('" + gid.ToString() + "', 'System.Guid')");
```

hope be useful ;)